# 'Not an answer' flag was declined

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged an 'answer' as Not-An-Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27492932/682404 but a moderator declined my flag (even though other readers have agreed with my note under the answer that it's just a comment).

I read through what should be considered a non-answer for flagging but I still don't quite understand why my flag was declined. The poster simply asked back a question and I have a really hard time seeing his answer as an actual attempt in solving the problem posed in the question.

Can someone please explain why my flag was turned down?

Comment: I actually disagree with those users. Its an answer, a poor one to a non-programming question, but an answer nonetheless.

Comment: They're humans and sometimes go wrong. Don't worry ...

Comment: What makes you think it's not an answer?  It looks very much like an answer to the question to me.  I have no idea if it's correct, but it's an answer.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET The answer doesn't provide any details, any links - it's only a comment with a technology thrown in. What's the point of Not-An-Answer if something like that cannot be flagged? I must be missing something.

Comment: Q: How do I turn on a computer over a network: A: Try "Wake-On LAN". I agree, its a *terrible* answer (they should have at least included the correct packet), but it *does* attempt to answer the question. You could have flagged for VLQ though

Comment: @Servy I was thinking that this answer could be one sentence in opening a conversation in the topic of the question but in and of itself, it's nothing but useless noise. (Well, at least that's how I read it, that's why I flagged it.)

Comment: Looks like an answer that starts with a rhetorical question (i.e. the answerer is actually proposing, under the guise of a question). On the one hand, it is not NAA. On the other hand, I still **hate** answers that start with a rhetorical question and are not followed by anything substantial (this still does not make it NAA).

Comment: @xxbbcc An *answer* that is poorly explained, or doesn't provide sufficient detail to be a quality answer, is still an answer.  It may be a *bad* answer, but it's an answer.  The flag is there for posts that *aren't answers at all*.

Comment: @Servy I have to admit, I have a hard time seeing the difference between a terribly worthless answer with no details and something that's _not an answer_. I'm trying to read that post as an attempted answer but no matter how I strain my mind, I cannot.

Comment: @xxbbcc "Thanks to bob for the answer." "I also have this problem. Did someone find a solution?" "I love cats." These are all non-answers. If there's an attempt at answering, then it is an answer.

Comment: @xxbbcc You called it an answer yourself.  Your only complaint about it is that it doesn't provide enough information.  NAA is for posts that don't *attempt* to answer the question, not for posts that attempt *and fail*.  It's perfectly fine for you to feel that the post is an *unsuccessful* attempt at answering the question.  The appropriate means of conveying that feedback is through downvotes, not flagging.  If the posts says something like, "Why would you want to do this?" then it's not even an *attempt* to answer the question, failed or otherwise.  That's when you flag.

Comment: @Servy Why do you say I called it an answer? I even added a comment to it (now deleted by a mod I guess) that it's not an answer but a comment. I only wrote 'answer' in my post because it's techically an SO answer under a question post.

Comment: Well, thanks for the replies. I won't accept the answers here (not out of spite or anger, but because I fundamentally disagree with them). I'll probably refrain from using NAA in the future because I find its definition very vague.

Comment: @xxbbcc -- I agree with your decision, not only are the answers vague but the rules about "link only" answers and NAA as well are strictly based on personal judgment and situational perception..

Answer (score 6):

Have you thought that maybe the answer was actually an answer and that's why your flag was declined?

All kidding aside, it is an answer.  It's not a great answer, and it probably warrants a downvote, but it is an answer.

It's an answer because the author proposes a solution:

> options such as "wake on LAN" and IPMI

and goes on to say (marginally) why they solve the problem:

> They provide mechanisms for this. They run from within the BIOS and preform [sic] what you're asking.

Comment: Unfortunately I was all out of downvotes because hats.

Comment: Yes, I did consider that it could be an answer but no matter how I look at it, I don't see it as an answer that has any value in staying on SO. Future visitors won't gain anything by reading it (the question itself is really bad) and the OP surely didn't get anything out of it.

Comment: @xxbbcc If you think that an answer is a bad answer, then the medium you have to convey that feedback is through downvotes.  Claiming that an answer is not an answer, just because you think it's a bad answer, will just result in your flag getting declined.  When you see a post that is *actually* not an answer, not just an answer that you think is bad or that you don't like, then you should be flagging it as NAA.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The damn hats ruin everything!!!

Answer (score 5):

The answerer is not asking a new question, it is more like *Have you thought about using...* which is understandable given the poor quality of the question.

So it definitely is an answer and therefor your NAA flag is declined.

The downvotes on the answer might be considered harsh but should drive the message home that such poor questions are better not answered (and if answered, answered correctly). In the future we should hope the answerer leaves a comment instead and the OP asks a better researched question.

Comment: Downvotes seem *entirely* warranted.  What the OP is saying is that it's a bad answer.  Flagging it is wrong, because it's an answer, but downvoting a bad answer (because it, for example, is so egregiously lacking in detail) is entirely warranted.

Comment: @Servy agreed, slightly adapted my wording.