# Shouldn't mods add comments when deleting posts that aren't obviously terrible?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleted-answers, moderators

[This post](//stackoverflow.com/a/29729312/2025923) in my opinion answers the question, has two upvotes, and should not have been deleted. The OP also confirms that it has solved the problem. And yet, after two days a mod has deleted the post.

[image: screenshot]

The only reason I see is poor wording by the answerer, using phrases like *I guess*, *try*, *Let us know...*, which can be edited and removed or changed. Apart from that, I don't see any reason to delete the post.

The other answer is of same quality, and is not deleted. My suggestion is that mods should add a comment with the reason for deletion to such posts (*I'm not saying to every post: not plagiarised posts, or offensive/rude posts.*).

**Note:** <strike>I know, I can vote to undelete the answer, but that's different thing.</strike> I'm curious about the reason.

Comment: *"I know, I can vote to Undelete the answer"* Actually, you can't, try it.

Comment: We already leave comments when deleting posts that aren't obviously terrible. The one who deleted this answer thought it *was*. That's the problem.

Comment: @BoltClock post as answer? Slightly terse, clearly correct. I'd also add that mods have a lot of work and finite time.

Comment: FWIW, at the time that answer was posted the author didn't have enough [rep](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3964806/naveenkumar-chinnakalappa?tab=reputation) to comment: they were still very new to SO and had just been downvoted to oblivion. Note: I'm _not_ saying they should therefore be allowed to post a comment as an answer, I'm just trying to shed some light on what happened.

Comment: Only by looking at the answer I knew there was a good chance the question should be closed/deleted. And yes, it has been deleted already. So who cares about the answer.

Comment: While I actually haven't seen an answer get deleted, I support the idea that negative actions should come with comments. Yes, it may take a little more effort for the mod or vigil ante, but I think in the long run it not only leads to higher **quality** posts via education, it also supports the **growth** of the StackOverflow platform (whereas swift, silent justice may help with quality but hurts participation and thus growth). Growth is good for all of us. It keeps the site funded, makes our rep worth more to potential employers, and it means more questions getting answered quickly.

Comment: That's a duplicate question (bordering on unclear) with answers that are variously [a vague suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729312/129032) (the answer this is about) and [another vague comment-as-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29729383/129032) (the meta-OP's answer). Almost everything on that page should be closed, deleted, or even flagged. Please don't encourage answers (or questions) like that.

Comment: You mention plagiarism and that's actually one time that it's really good to leave a note with a link to the source, because there's generally no other way to know that plagiarism is the issue. When I see posts deleted for plagiarism, mods generally have left such comments.

Answer (score 35):

This was terrible, and I don't see anything wrong with deleting it without a comment if it was obviously a non-answer to the moderator that deleted it. It was not obvious to me that it was a non-answer at first glance, but looking at it now, I fail to see how I could have read it as possibly valid.

The answer is saying that `jquery.ui.custom.js` is some custom version of JQuery, and suggests trying to change it to the official JQuery version to see if that makes any difference. That's very much wrong, but being wrong is not a valid reason for deletion. What is, is that it only attempts to help the OP with a first step in debugging the problem, and that means it should have been a comment or not posted at all.

The fact that this prompted the OP to *add* the missing JQuery reference instead of doing what the answer suggested doesn't redeem it.

Answer (score 18):

There's an easy way to redeem the post: make it an answer.  Of course, the question itself is a duplicate of a better question with better answers; so that may be moot.

Moderator actions are designed to be easily reversible*, so if you think we've made a mistake, feel free to flag the post and explain what's wrong with what we did.

We generally leave comments when actions are borderline; I didn't judge this one to be a borderline action.

*except for merges; which is why they're more rare

Comment: And ... "don't complain about the actions of a forum moderator until you've walked a mile in his/her moccasins!"  **:-)** A more grueling, thankless job probably can't be imagined, and yet, the (high!) quality of these forums utterly depends on what they do.  *(P.S.  That means, "Thanks.")*

Comment: ...designed for be reversible *for other moderators*. Omitting that is sort of misleading in this case, since normal users' actions are all reversible by any other user, and the question is specifically about moderator deletion of an answer. (Not disagreeing with your decision to delete in this case, though.)

Comment: The assumption is once you've flagged it for a moderator, you've said, "we can't handle this on our own", so the "reversible by other moderators" is implicit.

Comment: "make it an answer" This was more than a year ago, so I don't expect you to remember your exact train of thought in that particular moment, but can you explain why you're now saying that "You're not including the proper library, make sure it's this one" is _not an answer_? I don't even speak JS and I'm still pretty sure that I can figure out how to solve the problem with this information.

Comment: @JoshCaswell There are a whole class of 'non-answers' that give the user information they can use to piece together to solve the problem. If we use the definition of 'anything that provides a morsel to help solve the problem' is an answer, then by definition most (if not all) comments are answers.

Comment: Yes, I was pretty sure [that was part of the official operating definition](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315750/). [And](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280347/). [Also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315137/). [Plus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315135/dealing-with-answers-to-which-neither-very-low-quality-nor-not-an-anwer-appl/315137#comment296812_315137). [Previously](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277281/). [See also](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267382/603977).

Comment: @Mike Robinson: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: It is, first and foremost, a **public place**, where people in a certain profession gather to ask questions and to give answers.  Lots of people have slightly (or, not-so slightly) differences in their opinion of what it "ought to be."  I think that maybe we should all just, "strive to be **social**," and ... **polite** to the *complete strangers" whom we regularly "meet" here.  And, for the most part, if someone offers their contribution, let it stand.  They took time-and-effort to write it.  Let's presume that their intentions were good and sincere.

Comment: @MikeRobinson I politely tell you that you are wrong, so please, make sure your posts always meet the guidelines and be [always honest](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: I equally-politely yield to your point, and thank you for sharing it.  But, some of the points (officially!) made, go against my personal preferences, such as: "vote it down."  I don't vote anything *down,* on any forum where I regularly participate, even when given the opportunity to do so. I will very quickly vote *up* anything that I found useful. I will sometimes post a comment *questioning* a published comment, asking for clarification, but I always choose to assume that others know more about such things than I do. I yield, nonetheless, to your comment, and thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I think it **shouldn't** be deleted. It *does* answer the question:

> Indeed, I lost this include in the other file ... And didn't
>   noted 'ui' there:) Thanks a lot

I'm not familiar with subject being discussed, and I'm aware that the answer might be incorrect, doesn't follow best practices or might have bad side-effects - in such case, I would downvote it and write a comment explaining my vote, but I don't think it should be deleted for that.

The user doesn't have a high reputation, and used "bad" words for an answer: "I guess", "Let us know".. In such case, I would have edited the post, made it better and dropped a comment to help the user in his future posts.

Answer (score -7):

I've been around SO a long time (look at my rep), and frankly I've been distressed by what appears to me to a shift from "let's give helpful answers to everyone" to "let's show just how smart we are by making fun of (or deleting) questions we don't like." Examples like this, or deleting long-standing, accepted answers with high vote totals, make SO less usable for beginners and frustrating for old-timers.

Comment: Other people are similarly distressed by what appears to them to be a shift from "smart answers to smart questions" to "let's give some response to everyone, no matter how helpful". The truth probably lies somewhere in the middle. Still, in this particular case, I agree: I don't understand why the answer needed to be deleted by a moderator.

Comment: "let's show just how smart we are by making fun of (or deleting) questions we don't like."  - you're just assuming bad intentions, in a not very elegant way, which is far from constructive.

Comment: My goodness, you mean I just expressed an opinion you don't like? I'm devastated.

Comment: And, in too-many forums, I have seen what I consider to be a *negative* influence caused by "feedback," whether that feedback is "plus" or(!) "minus." One of the influences of most concern to me is that posts "get voted off the island" and disappear. And, the *reason* for my concern on this point is that, to me, "a relevant thread on a forum" might be of great value to me *many years after* it was made! I want those "old" threads to still be around, no matter what "the internecine politics of the day" might or might not have been.