# Why was my "how to boost OS keyrate" answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

EDIT: This site has gotten... weird lately. Now this question is closed as a duplicate? Somehow multiple people thought me asking about why my specific answer was closed was a *duplicate* of someone asking why moderators don't leave comments when closing posts? o.O

I just noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11056655/501459) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W5mjA.png)) was deleted by Stack Overflow employee [Geoff Dalgas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2/geoff-dalgas). It was the most popular answer to the question and has been on the site for years.

There is no reason given, just a link to a [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) which offers no insight. My answer didn't mention other answers, didn't ask a question, didn't duplicate another response, etc.

Comment: I got nothin'. No one flagged your post. And I can't see why your answer would have been deleted. I'm not sure if the fact that Geoff is a Stack Overflow dev means anything (I doubt it - what's that got to do with your utility?).

Comment: I imagine it came up in a security report somewhere due to the fact that the ZIP file you link sets off anti-virus software for a virus being detected. Perhaps didn't look at it closely enough? Pretty sure that link could easily be removed. He deleted six posts that day which all have links to virus-infected files.

Comment: Mmm, I'm sure it's legit, but that is one *sketchy-looking* URL.

Comment: Hmm.... why would the zip file set off a virus warning? The utility therein contains exactly one completely innocent system call. What heuristic would that trigger, unless it's "detection" based on something obnoxiously trivial such as the filename containing the word "key"? Given that I included the source code to the utility itself, why wouldn't the moderator simply remove the link rather than delete a useful answer? More importantly, is there any recourse to get it reevaluated? The "undelete" button results in a popup saying "A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted".

Comment: Same reason I asked [Shouldn't mods add comments when deleting posts that aren't obviously terrible?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326862/shouldnt-mods-add-comments-when-deleting-posts-that-arent-obviously-terrible)

Comment: No way this should be closed. Mods? :>

Comment: If the link was the problem why not just edit out the link? Then people could still compile themselves.

Comment: @Mud If the zip only contains code, consider putting it on Github. Either way, I'm looking forward to seeing Geoff's response to this :)

Comment: I haven't seen anyone mention it, but keep in mind the individual who deleted is technically not a moderator, but a Stack Exchange developer.  It is extremely unusual for a develop to be taking moderation actions on this site, which supports the idea that he felt the link to the exe was the problem or threat

Comment: @Lankymart I was just thinking that...

Comment: @AshleyMedway: Given that 6 posts were closed by the same SO developer, I am thinking that he may have used a script to automatically delete any post with "threatening" content.

Comment: Meh, one can argue that the question itself is off topic for the site...

Comment: @Braiam I'm not sure I understand your point. Deleting a question/an answer with good content is counter-productive, even if the question is off-topic.

Comment: @VincentSavard counter productive is keeping examples that off topic questions are OK.

Comment: @Braiam That's complete non-sense. The web is now a little bit worse because good content was deleted. The question is off-topic? Fine, close it. But don't remove valuable content just because StackOverflow no longer accepts this kind of questions.

Comment: @VincentSavard [yeah](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39899998), [lets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891491/) [do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39891289/), [what](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890045/) [could](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886862/) [go wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39878668/)

Comment: @Braiam Once again, what's your point? You're conflating several issues here. There is a question that used to be on-topic and attracted many good answers. StackOverflow's scope changed, so the question is now off-topic. Are you really arguing that since it is now off-topic for StackOverflow, it should simply be deleted?

Comment: @VincentSavard my point is [that users get confused about what the site is about](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279661/213575), having high profile questions as examples of what the site is not about doesn't help.

Comment: @VincentSavard it's the broken window theory... Lurk on meta a bit, you will see a lot of new users linking questions from 4-5 years ago as examples of why THEIR (now) off topic question should stay

Comment: @Braiam, Yes, but that is just an argument that we should be either close such old questions as off-topic, or delete them. SO's method for dealing with all such questions is clear: we close them. We do not actively delete them. We then show new users with new similar questions that such questions are off-topic and will be closed. Theirs get deleted because they are not highly up-voted (and probably down-voted).

Comment: @Makyen yeah, lets allow people to see on the site high profile questions that are closed... nevermind that they consider they shouldn't be closed in first place, [since we upvoted them they should be alright anyways, correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39927303/792066)

Comment: @Braiam, I'm not sure what you are trying to show with the question you linked. That question is closed. Neither of the questions which that OP linked as examples were "high profile" (0score +4/-4; 2score +2/-0). The 0 score question has been closed (off-topic: off-site rec.), the other is iffy (not specifically asking for off-site resources, but could be viewed that way). New users who don't read the links in the help center are going to be confused. There are millions of questions. Not all will have been handled correctly, even for the time they were posted, let alone to today's standards.

Comment: @Makyen did you even checked the timeline? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3518972/timeline 3 of the downvotes were done *today/yesterday*. At the time, the user saw a question with score 3 and through it was ok, imagine what would they think if the score was 30 or 300... bullying! Free speech! We are a bunch of elitist that oppress the weak!

Answer (score 49):

As explained by animuson, the ZIP file you linked to (which contains an `.exe`) is probably the reason why your answer was deleted.

You may have created a perfectly innocuous executable, but... that's really not the issue.

**We should teach people never to download executables or libraries from random sites on Internet.**

There are enough security issues downloading them from "trusted" sites (thanks, SourceForge...), trusting random sites is *really* asking for troubles:

- no proof that the author is not malicious
- no proof that the artifact was not corrupted/exchanged after being uploaded
- no proof that the website you link to has not been taken over by a malicious entity

---

So what to do?

I would suggest that you remove the offending link from your answer. Your answer is great without it, just remove the:

> You can get it here (includes source).

bit and you should be good to go.

Then you can flag your answer with a custom flag, asking a moderator to undelete it now that the link has been removed.

And in the future, avoid linking to executables/libraries that are not hosted on reputable websites (in doubt, just don't link).

Comment: This *might* be the reason, but who knows for sure until Geoff comes along and tells us why he did it? It also doesn't explain why he didn't just edit out the link, or notify OP why it was being deleted.

Comment: @DavidG: I am wondering if maybe this kind of deletion is not scripted (which would explain why it cannot be smart)... but once again we'll need Geoff to answer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. An automated deletion could automatically comment as well…

Comment: @Bergi: It could, if the script is smart enough... but I was more talking about the "editing" bit. I don't see a script knowing exactly which portion of the answer to excise/amend to leave a useful and well-formed answer behind.

Comment: Can the OP still edit the answer though if it's been nuked by a SO staff member? - *"A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted"*.

Comment: @Lankymart: I can edit it, but cannot undelete it. I assume the OP can too, otherwise I volunteer to edit it for him.

Comment: Looks like we need @geoff-dalgas then...anyone contacted him? Could tweet him...

Comment: @Lankymart: I asked the staff to pass it on to him earlier today.

Comment: Well, then let's remove all the links from SO. You never know what it links to. I can create a site which renders a HTML site when you look at it but downloads a malicious ZIP file when someone else looks at it.

Comment: "We should teach people never to download executables or libraries from random sites on Internet." - how do we teach them when we actually remove the links where they can learn from? This is not teaching, it's preventing or censoring.

Comment: Why not ask the OP to sign his executable instead of deleting? Then you have all the proofs you want. This answer is not consistent and seems to prefer the action of the moderator instead of considering other alternatives.

Comment: @Thomas: This answer *explains* the actions of the developer, and why there probably a security report in the first place. It also provides advice on how to get the OP's answer back into the realm of the living. It does NOT attempt to discuss what changes to whatever policy is in place should be enacted: you expected too much :)

Comment: @Thomas because you can sign malicious code just as easily as good code. This is a programming site, so providing the source (instead of a mysterious binary) is typically the better choice.

Comment: @ssube: if someone signs malicious code, it should be easy to get him arrested, no? In addition, the source was already provided, so anyone who does not trust the certificate may still compile it himself.

Comment: @Thomas You're not signing it with a legal signature; you're just signing the file to prove that it hasn't been tampered with (if it has, the signature will be different and therefore invalid). It's meant to prove that the last person who edited it was `x`, but doesn't necessarily prove *who `x` actually is!*

Comment: @wizzwizz4: what do I pay DigiCert for, then, if not to verify that I am actually I? I had to give them a copy of my passport and I had to sign during a live video session. Of course, a signed executable with a self-generated certificate is worthless, but that's not what I'm talking about. If you were right, why should I trust executables signed by Microsoft?

Comment: @Thomas DigiCert Is a certificate authority that will only give you a valid certificate after proving that you have an irl identity. Microsoft's certificate authority, however, will give a certificate to anyone who runs their compiler with the right parameters (and I mean their internal compiler, not Visual Studio). There are certificate authorities who would give *me* a certificate, and I am a bot! (I mean, no I'm not... Not a bot. But if I were, they'd still give me one... :-/)

Comment: @wizzwizz4: this will result in an endless discussion about digital certificates. I'll not follow up.